# Android imagebutton in custom listview is null

Tags: android, android-listview, android-fragments, android-dialog, android-dialogfragment

i am developing an android app, which displays a listview. When i click some of the items of the listview it should open a dialog, which includes another (custom) listview. the listview in the dialog has two textviews and one (image)button (i tried both). but i am getting always a nullpointerException and i have no idea, what i am doing wrong.

here is my code

```
    public class Schuldet_mir extends Fragment {

    private ListView mainList;
    private ListView subList;
    .....

    MainActivity mainActivity = (MainActivity) getActivity();
    .....


    public Schuldet_mir(int position) {                                                                         
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {         //onCreate

        View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_schuldet_mir, container, false);

        mainList        = (ListView)v.findViewById(R.id.listView1);
        imageButton     = (ImageButton)v.findViewById(R.id.imageBtn1);


        imageButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {                                      
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                openDialog();
            }
        });

        mainList.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {                                             //Hauptliste klick

            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View v, int position, long idInDB) {

                mainListViewClick(parent, v, position, idInDB);
            }           
        });

        return v;
    }

    @Override                                                                                                   //onResume
    public void onResume() {
        super.onResume();

        populateListViewFromDB();   
    }


    private void openDialog() {                                                                                 

        final Dialog dialog1 = new Dialog(getActivity());                   
        dialog1.setContentView(R.layout.dialog1);
        dialog1.setTitle("Schuldner hinzufügen");
        dialog1.setCancelable(false);

        eintrag_name   = (EditText)dialog1.findViewById(R.id.editText_name);
        eintrag_betrag = (EditText)dialog1.findViewById(R.id.editText_betrag);
        eintrag_grund  = (EditText)dialog1.findViewById(R.id.editText1);

        ImageButton hinzufügen = (ImageButton)dialog1.findViewById(R.id.imageButton_add);
        ImageButton abbrechen = (ImageButton)dialog1.findViewById(R.id.imageButton_cancel);

        hinzufügen.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {                                                   //Buttonklick Hinzufügen 

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                                                                //do s.th.

                }
            }
        });


        abbrechen.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {                                                    

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                dialog1.dismiss();                      
            }
        });

        dialog1.show();                 
    }


    private void mainListViewClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View v, int position, long idInDB) {                  

        final Dialog dialog3 = new Dialog(getActivity());                                                       
        dialog3.setContentView(R.layout.dialog3);
        dialog3.setTitle("Schuldner");
        dialog3.setCancelable(false);

        subList                 = (ListView)dialog3.findViewById(R.id.dialog3_listView);
        Button deleteBtn        = (Button)dialog3.findViewById(R.id.dialog3_deleteBtn);
        Button allesErhalten    = (Button)dialog3.findViewById(R.id.dialog3_btn1);
        Button zurück           = (Button)dialog3.findViewById(R.id.dialog3_btn2);

        populateSubListViewFromDB(idInDB);

        subList.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View v, int position, long idInDB) {

                subListViewClick(parent, v, position, idInDB);              
            }
        });

        deleteBtn.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {  **// line:193**                                                       /

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Log.e("++++++++", "TEST OK");                       
            }
        });

        allesErhalten.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            }
        });

        zurück.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                dialog3.dismiss();
            }
        });

        dialog3.show(); 
    }

//  --------------------------------------------------------------------
    private void subListViewClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View v, int position, long idInDB) {                   // SubList Item Click

        cursor = mainActivity.myDBHandler.getRowinTable1(idInDB);       

        if(cursor.moveToFirst()) {                                                                              //informationen der zeile
            idDB = cursor.getLong(DataBaseHandler.COL_ROWID);
            dialog2_name = cursor.getString(DataBaseHandler.COL_NAME);
            dialog2_betrag = cursor.getFloat(DataBaseHandler.COL_BETRAG);
            dialog2_grund = cursor.getString(DataBaseHandler.COL_GRUND);
            dialog2_datum = cursor.getString(DataBaseHandler.COL_DATUM);            
        }

        final Dialog dialog2 = new Dialog(getActivity());                                                       //open dialog
        dialog2.setContentView(R.layout.dialog2);
        dialog2.setTitle("Schuldner");
        dialog2.setCancelable(false);

        TextView dial2_TxtDatum  = (TextView)dialog2.findViewById(R.id.dialog2_TxtDatum);
        TextView dial2_TxtName   = (TextView)dialog2.findViewById(R.id.dialog2_TxtName);
        TextView dial2_TxtGrund  = (TextView)dialog2.findViewById(R.id.dialog2_TxtGrund);
        TextView dial2_TxtBetrag = (TextView)dialog2.findViewById(R.id.dialog2_TxtBetrag);

        Button erhalten = (Button)dialog2.findViewById(R.id.dialog2_btnBezahlt);
        Button ok = (Button)dialog2.findViewById(R.id.dialog2_btnOk);

        NumberFormat currencyFormatter = NumberFormat.getCurrencyInstance(Locale.getDefault());
        String currencyOut = currencyFormatter.format(dialog2_betrag);

        dial2_TxtDatum.setText("Vom " + dialog2_datum + " Uhr");
        dial2_TxtName.setText(dialog2_name);
        dial2_TxtGrund.setText(dialog2_grund);
        dial2_TxtBetrag.setText(currencyOut);


        erhalten.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {                                                     //Buttonklick für erhalten
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                mainActivity.myDBHandler.deleteRowInTable1(idDB);
                populateListViewFromDB();
                dialog2.dismiss();
            }
        });

        ok.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {                                                           //Buttonklick für ok
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                dialog2.dismiss();
            }
        });

        dialog2.show();
    }

//  --------------------------------------------------------------------
    @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
    public void populateListViewFromDB() {              ...
    }   

//  --------------------------------------------------------------------
    @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
    public void populateSubListViewFromDB(long idInDB) {        

    getActivity().startManagingCursor(cursor = mainActivity.myDBHandler.getAllEntriesFromAPerson1(idInDB));

    String[] dbSpaltenNamen = new String[] {"d", "b"};

    int[] zuListViewIDs = new int[] {R.id.dialog3_datum, R.id.dialog3_lz_betrag};

    SimpleCursorAdapter myCursorAdapter 
            = new SimpleCursorAdapter
                        (getActivity(), R.layout.dialog3_listzeile, cursor, dbSpaltenNamen, zuListViewIDs);

    subList.setAdapter(myCursorAdapter);
    }

//  --------------------------------------------------------------------
    @Override
    public void onAttach(Activity activity) {
        super.onAttach(activity);
        try {
            mainActivity = (MainActivity) activity;
        } 
        catch (ClassCastException e) {
            throw new ClassCastException(activity.toString() +  " Fehler: Keine MainActivity-Instanz!");
        }
    }
}
```

the logcat message:

```
01-10 18:10:19.392: E/AndroidRuntime(14649): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
01-10 18:10:19.392: E/AndroidRuntime(14649): java.lang.NullPointerException
01-10 18:10:19.392: E/AndroidRuntime(14649):    at fragments.Schuldet_mir.mainListViewClick(Schuldet_mir.java:193)
01-10 18:10:19.392: E/AndroidRuntime(14649):    at fragments.Schuldet_mir.access$1(Schuldet_mir.java:171)
01-10 18:10:19.392: E/AndroidRuntime(14649):    at fragments.Schuldet_mir$2.onItemClick(Schuldet_mir.java:90)
01-10 18:10:19.392: E/AndroidRuntime(14649):    at android.widget.AdapterView.performItemClick(AdapterView.java:298)
01-10 18:10:19.392: E/AndroidRuntime(14649):    at android.widget.AbsListView.performItemClick(AbsListView.java:1111)
01-10 18:10:19.392: E/AndroidRuntime(14649):    at android.widget.AbsListView$PerformClick.run(AbsListView.java:2900)
01-10 18:10:19.392: E/AndroidRuntime(14649):    at android.widget.AbsListView$1.run(AbsListView.java:3728)
01-10 18:10:19.392: E/AndroidRuntime(14649):    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:615)
01-10 18:10:19.392: E/AndroidRuntime(14649):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
01-10 18:10:19.392: E/AndroidRuntime(14649):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
01-10 18:10:19.392: E/AndroidRuntime(14649):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4872)
01-10 18:10:19.392: E/AndroidRuntime(14649):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
01-10 18:10:19.392: E/AndroidRuntime(14649):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
01-10 18:10:19.392: E/AndroidRuntime(14649):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:790)
01-10 18:10:19.392: E/AndroidRuntime(14649):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:557)
01-10 18:10:19.392: E/AndroidRuntime(14649):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

the line 193 is the deleteBtn.setOnClickListener method. what i am doing wrong!? thanks in advance for advices

EDIT:
dialog3.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical" >

<ListView
    android:id="@+id/dialog3_listView"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dip"
    android:layout_weight="0.98" >
</ListView>

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="46dp" >

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/dialog3_btn1"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:text="Alles erhalten" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/dialog3_btn2"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:text="Zurück" />
</LinearLayout>
```

dialog3_listzeile: that is the custom row for the listview

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent" >

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/dialog3_datum"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:text="Medium Text"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
    android:textStyle="italic" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/dialog3_deleteBtn"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:focusable="false"
    android:text="Delete" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/dialog3_lz_betrag"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/dialog3_deleteBtn"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:text="Large Text"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
    android:textStyle="bold" />
```

Comment: Even though this will not be the solution to your problem you shouldn't use 'ä', 'ü' or 'ö' for variable names.

Comment: can you pls post `dialog3.xml`. looks like wrong id referenced

Comment: @Raghunandan the id is correct referenced. i posted the xmls

Comment: then that line can't be null. if it is null then its the wrong id referenced

Answer (score 0):

You try to find the `dialog3_deleteBtn` in your activities' `layout`. This won't work as it is part of your `row` in the `ListView`.
You have to write a custom adapter instead which can handle the buttonclicks inside each row.

Furthermore, as I said in the comments section already, you shouldn't use 'ä','ü', 'ö' or similiar letters in your code.
For 'ü' you can use 'ue' instead.

*Zudem solltest du dir angewöhnen möglichst auch auf Englisch zu 'coden', damit möglichst viele deinen Code besser verstehen.*

Comment: thx for your advices. As raghunandan said, it doesnt worked after all. the same error message. (danke)

Comment: @user1953173 I think you have to write a custom adapter to handle the buttonclicks inside the rows as you won't be able to fetch them otherwise.

Comment: @user1953173 your code is absolutely confusing and hard to debug. Pls  change the way you code. Post the adapter code also

Comment: the adapter is in the method populateSubListViewFromDB(). i posted it

Comment: @user1953173 No, you haven't created a custom adapter. You just use a SimpleCursorAdapter.

_SimpleCursorAdapter myCursorAdapter 
            = new SimpleCursorAdapter
                        (getActivity(), R.layout.dialog3_listzeile, cursor, dbSpaltenNamen, zuListViewIDs)_;

You can extend SimpleCursorAdapter and while inflating each row you can add a listener to the button.

Answer (score 0):

`dialog3.xml` does not have a button with id `R.id.dialog3_deleteBtn`

`findViewById` looks for a view with the id in the current inflated layout. So it gives you `NullPointerException`.

You have this in `dialog3_listzeile.xml`

```
<Button
android:id="@+id/dialog3_deleteBtn"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
```

It should be

```
Button deleteBtn = (Button)dv.findViewById(R.id.dialog3_deleteBtn);
```

Apart of that.

```
MainActivity mainActivity = (MainActivity) getActivity();
```

is also wrong

`getActivity()` will return null. Move it to `onCreateView`

Comment: i know. the listview is a custom listview. the single row of that listview have a button.

Comment: @user1953173 then use  `Button deleteBtn  = (Button)dv.findViewById(R.id.dialog3_deleteBtn);` The `onItemClick` has a `View v` as a param. so use that to initialize your button

Comment: @user1953173 i also suggest you edit your post and make it clear to us. Its very confusing and we haven't seen the adapter code and we don't know where the button is

Comment: @user1953173 try the code in my comment and tell me if it works

Comment: @user1953173 1.you don't have ImageButton 2. You don't have custom adapter. 3. You should post only relevant code.  4. Make the post clear to us so that we can help. Your coding not only is confusing but also confusing and hard to debug for others.

Comment: @user1953173 try this.`View view =(View) v.getParent()`then Button `deleteBtn = (Button)view.findViewById(R.id.dialog3_deleteBtn);`. before this try `Button deleteBtn = (Button)v.findViewById(R.id.dialog3_deleteBtn);` i had posted `dv` instead of `v`.

Comment: i said, i used both of buttons, an imagebutton and a normal button. its the same result. yes it is my mistake, sry. i used a simplecursoradapter.

Comment: @user1953173 sorry i can't help further coz its very confusing and you have not specified anything that would help us solve your problem. No more wasting time on this. I don't see a `ImageButton` anywhere

Comment: understandable, it is a little bit complicated. thanks for your help